# Authorize web app to connect to previously connected third-party services

Tags: facebook, oauth

Our dashboard web app incorporates API feeds from multiple third-party membership websites. When we're on-boarding a new user, we'd like to use FB Connect and OAuth to

1. verify identity of user
2. grant permission to our app to access FB graph data, and
3. determine if the user has previously approved some of those third-party services we incorporate.

We would like the user to be able to grant us permission to connect those services on behalf of the user as well, all in one OAuth session. Is this possible?

I.e. if we provide FB with a list of our services that we connect to, can we get a yes/no from FB Connect as to whether the user has pre-approved those services elsewhere using FB Connect? Then, we would provide a secondary approval page to the user saying "looks like you've already logged in to these X, Y, and Z apps which we use in our dashboard. Would you like to grant us access to those apps as well and pull them in to your dashboard?"

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a feature of the Facebook API - you'll need to use each site's Oauth flow in succession